# Comprehensive list of the usable variables in Semantic-Ui?

Tags: documentation, semantic-ui

Is there a comprehensive variable list of all the things that can be customized in `Semantic-Ui`? Like `@floatingBoxShadow`, `@iconSize`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 1.0, your best bet is to check out the default theme folder located at `semantic/src/themes/default/`. Within `globals/site.variables` you'll find the site wide variables similar to Bootstrap, but the similarities stop there. Each `collection`, `element`, `module`, and `view` have their own variables associated with them.